# Problems with figures: underfull \vbox, and the final two figures don't print

Tags: floats

I'm in the last stages of preparation for an academic paper, and I've got a couple of LaTeX problems that nobody in my group knows how to fix (in a way that will be leave the resulting `.pdf` in any condition worthy of publication).

The first is one that might be ignorable. Every figure in the paper (there's ~25 of them) triggers a error that says:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active.
```

I've attempted to fix it through the use of `\enlargethispage` and `\pagebreak`, but both of those lead to other errors. The figures that do show up don't appear to be in the wrong place, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

The second is that LaTeX just doesn't print the final two figures. I know a workaround for this; add in a huge amount of placeholder text (about 6 pages worth), and the figures print just fine (at the cost of making it unpublishable; who would accept a paper with 6 pages of Lorem Ipsum?). I'm assuming this results from LaTeX thinking it doesn't have the space to print them while staying aesthetically pleasing; attempts to create space to print them with `\newpage` at the end of the file don't work.

Does anyone know any possible solutions for either of these issues?

Comment: It's difficult to help without seeing _any_ of your code. When writing manuscripts, I usually adjust the float-fractions in the document to relax the typesetting rules, ie allow to stick a figure onto a page with very little text, stick more figures on a page etc.:
`\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.85}`
`\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.15}`
`\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.75}`
`\setcounter{topnumber}{2}`
`\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}`
There's more of the commands for bottomfigures etc., some explanations eg. here: http://aty.sdsu.edu/~aty/bibliog/latex/floats.html

Comment: if figures do not print then there is an error in either your document,  or a package it loads or in the latex format, but impossible to debug code that we can not see. Please make a document that shows the problem you can use `example-image` for images and any made up text but start from a copy of your document and check the problem still shows in the test file.

Comment: Usually `\clearpage` should be sufficient, to eject all floats, that are put in hold in the deffered-floats-queue.  There is an excellent [article about floats](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/tb111mitt-float.pdf) from Frank Mittelbach.  You should read that.  Underfull-vbox-errors occur, when LaTeX was forced to eject an almost empty page.  You can force by choosing the wrong floating paramaters. Enlarging the page is contra-productive in this case.  As pointed out by Wiebke and David: please create an working example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.  Everything else is

Comment: @Jan but there is a `\clearpage` at `\end{document}` so while it may be needed to force figures at a certain point it should never be needed to force figures to appear at all.